# how can i pass the json without escape sequence in curl?

Tags: bash

I have to post JSON as request in cURL as

`curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/users.json\ -d "{"user" : {"email":"sample@example.com", "password":"qwerty", "password_confirmation":"qwerty"}}"`

but this displays a `Multi_json decode` error.

It accepts this instead.

`curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/users.json -d "{\"user\" : {\"email\":\"sample@example.com\", \"password\":\"qwerty\", \"password_confirmation\":\"qwerty\"}}"`

How can I send the JSON without escaping it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with rails

Comment: Actually i have cloned an example from https://github.com/plataformatec/devise_example  and there i have passed the values without escape sequence and it worked but not working on others.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with cURL or JSON.

The real question here is: "How do I pass an argument containing quote characters in bash?" (or whatever shell is being used to access the command line curl application).

Quote the string with `'` characters instead of `"` characters.

This will only work if the data does not include `'` characters.

Comment: And if the data *does* include `'` characters, then what?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78063919/can-i-do-without-aggressive-escaping-when-executing-my-curls-with-json-payload) (even if the data doesn't include apostrophes)