# Can I do without aggressive escaping when executing my curls with JSON payload?

Tags: json, windows, command-line, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm not comfortable with this heavy escaping in my curls

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"username\":\"john\",\"password\":\"12345\"}" http://localhost:8100/signup
```

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14195508/23434786). Single quotes are not accepted

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"username":"john","password":"12345"}' http://localhost:8100/signup
```

```
org.springframework.core.codec.DecodingException: 
JSON decoding error: Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): 
expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
```

This doesn't work as well (the exception is the same)

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{'username':'john','password':'12345'}" http://localhost:8100/signup
```

My curl version:

```
curl --version                                                                       
curl 8.4.0 (Windows) libcurl/8.4.0 Schannel WinIDN                                                  
Release-Date: 2023-10-11                                                                            
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s smtp smtps telnet tftp               
Features: AsynchDNS HSTS HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile NTLM SPNEGO SSL SSPI threadsafe Unicode UnixSockets
```

Can I do without that aggressive escaping when executing my curls with JSON payload (without payload files)?

## UPD

I debugged and discovered the exception is thrown from `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser` on a `nextToken()` invocation if its `_inputBuffer` (a byte array) starts with an apostrophe

I tried to write an MRE. It's tricky. The class has a ton of parameters, some of them are tricky to instantiate. Here's my best attempt. It does reproduce the error but since I pass nulls and mocks I can't be sure I *actually* mimic the actual case. Basically, if the method reaches the end without recognition of the first character (it has lots of ifs and switch cases), it throws that exception

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectCodec;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.IOContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.sym.ByteQuadsCanonicalizer;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.InputStream;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThatCode;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

public class GenericTest {
    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    void test() {
        IOContext context = mock(IOContext.class);
        int features = 65537;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        ObjectCodec codec = null;
        ByteQuadsCanonicalizer canonicalizer = null;
        String input = "'{}'";
        byte[] inputBuffer = input.getBytes();
        int start = 0;
        int end = input.length();
        byte bytesPreProcessed = 0;
        boolean bufferRecycleable = true;

        UTF8StreamJsonParser jsonParser = new UTF8StreamJsonParser(
                context, features, inputStream, codec,
                canonicalizer, inputBuffer, start, end,
                bytesPreProcessed, bufferRecycleable
                );

        assertThatCode(jsonParser::nextToken)
                // the exception is translated and rethrown by Spring
                .isInstanceOf(JsonParseException.class)
                .hasMessageContaining("Unexpected character (''' (code 39))");
    }
}
```

## UPD2

I tried Power Shell instead of Command Prompt. I couldn't make a request even with escaping, Shell threw all kinds of exceptions no matter what I tried

**Attempt #1**

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"username\":\"john\",\"password\":\"12345\"}" http://localhost:8100/signup
```

```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

**Attempt #2**

```
curl -i -X POST -H Content-Type:application/json -d {"username":"john","password":"12345"} http://localhost:8100/signup
```

```
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

**Attempt #3**

```
curl -i -X POST -H Content-Type:application/json -d {username:john,password:12345} http://localhost:8100/signup
```

```
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument
```

**Attempt #4**

```
curl -i -X POST -H Content-Type:application/json -d '{"username":"john","password":"12345"}' http://localhost:8100/signup
```

```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

**Attempt #5**

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"username":"john","password":"12345"}' http://localhost:8100/signup
```

```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Comment: How are you calling curl? Any *nix shell should be stripping out the surrounding quotes on your second example. Curl should never see them. We need more details.

Comment: @UncleCarl from `cmd.exe`

Answer (score 1):

Use a different shell (not cmd.exe or PowerShell), which supports single quotes for quoting command arguments. For example, Bash supports it. Bash is available on Windows e.g. in WSL2 and MSYS2.

This works in Bash:

```bash
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"username":"john","password":"12345"}' http://localhost:8100/signup
```

Alternatively, save the POST data to a file, and ask curl to read it from the file.

Comment: Thank you. Though using WSL seems a questionable alternative to escaping to me (more bother, not less)

Comment: You have multiple options, you don't have to use WSL2. The MSYS2 base system contains Bash, is lightweight and quick to try.

Answer (score 1):

### Linux Bash

```
-d '{"username":"john","password":"12345"}'
```

### Windows CMD

```
-d "{\"username\":\"john\",\"password\":\"12345\"}"
```

### Windows PowerShell

```
-d '{\"username\":\"john\",\"password\":\"12345\"}'
```

> *I'm not comfortable with this heavy escaping in my curls*

By adding JSON as a string, there's unfortunately no other way around it.